# Getting return type of swift function using awk/sed

Tags: swift, shell, awk, sed

I have few string which look like below

`internal func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) -> <<error type>>`

`internal func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool`

`internal func helloWorld()`

In these lines, I want to get the return type of the function which is present after `->`, however a function might not have return type (in which case it is default to `Void`

I need to write a shell script, preferably using `awk` or `sed` that can get me return type. However, it should return Void in 1st and 3rd case.

What did I try?
`cut -d ">" -f 2 <<< "$string"` - but, this is very simplistic and does work even in simple 3rd case, where it returns the original string as it.

Comment: I am not familiar with swift syntax. can a line of code max. have single `->` ? btw, is there swift related tool to do the code analysis? it would be more precise.

Comment: imho you should add the tag "swift"

Comment: Yes, it can have at max single `->`. I am using sourceKitten for rest of the information and further processing, but they do not give back return type.

Comment: There can be more than one `->`, e.g. if the function takes a closure argument, e.g. `func foo(cl: (Int) -> Int) -> Void {}` or `func bar(cl: ((Int) -> Int) -> Int) -> Void {}`.

Comment: I agree. Do you have suggestions, on how to modify the answer below?

Comment: @MartinR - can we safely assume that post `->` is return type?. But a function may not write any return type. What is the best way to get a return type of a Swift function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# -- all purpose (file with other line also like full source code) ---
sed -e '/ func /!d' -e '/->/!s/.*//;/.*-> */{s///;s/.*<<error type>>.*//;};s/^[[:blank:]]*$/void/' YourFile


# -- tiny adapted for string ---
YourStream | sed '/->/!s/.*/void/;s/.*-> *//;s/.*<<error type>>.*/void/'
```

Explain

- `/ func /!d` remove line without  `func`.
- `/->/!s/.*//` empty (delete content) line without `->`.
- `/.*-> */{...}` for lines with `->` (and preparing pattern for next `s///` from begin of line until last blank after `->`)

  - `s///` remove begining including `->` (from previous pattern matching).
  - `s/.*<<error type>>.*//` empty( delete content) `<<error type>>` lines
- `s/^[[:blank:]]*$/void/` set to `void` any empty line

Comment: All is fine with one case, `echo "internal func helloWorld(a: String)" | sed -e '/ func /!d' -e '/[.->.]/!s/.*//;/.*-> */{s///;s/.*<<error type>>.*//;};s/^[[:blank:]]*$/void/'` - in this case, the output is `internal func helloWorld(a: String)` - this should also be `Void`

Comment: Could you please help with this.

Comment: sorry i badly use collating class `[.->.]`, you only need to use `->`, I change the reply

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
awk -F"-> *" 'NF>0{print(NF==1?"Void":$NF=="<<error type>>"?"Void":$NF)}' file
```

See it live:

```
$ cat file
internal func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) -> <<error type>>

internal func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool

internal func helloWorld()

$ awk -F"-> *" 'NF>0{print(NF==1?"Void":$NF=="<<error type>>"?"Void":$NF)}' file
Void
Bool
Void
```

Comment: Can we also ignore this <<error type>> to void?. Also, can this input be taken from string, instead of a file.

Comment: Could this input be taken from string, instead of a file.

Comment: @prabodhprakash - done; if the input taken from the string, use echo 'string' | awk ......

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. I'm little weak on awk/sed thing !